# PHP printing its own code

Tags: php, server, instagram-api

I have this code:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/////// CONFIG ///////
$username = 'NetsGets';
$password = 'NetsGetsWebsite';
$debug = true;
$truncatedDebug = false;
//////////////////////

$ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram($debug, $truncatedDebug);

try {
    $ig->login($username, $password);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit(0);
}

?>
```

When I run this code, it just prints the code and not what it should run... Why is it not running the code? (I am using Instagram private API for PHP btw).

Comment: Enabled PHP on your server?

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Depends on your OS really, tons of tutorials/readmes on the interweb

Comment: I am using ubuntu and apache2

Comment: Search for `libapache2-mod-php`, install the one fitting your PHP version